# How to disable loop playback of animation?

Tags: animation, timeline

Is there a way to stop looping playback in the timeline? I want to avoid sending additional animation data from blender by stopping the animation at the end frame and in another case to prevent recording of animation from the end to start frame.

Comment: maybe a script with frame change handler

Comment: @Chebhou I guess that may work, but as in any software with playback there is an option to disable looping and I cant find it anywhere in blender.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently up to version 2.74 there is no option to disable looping playback.
There is a solution with a script from CoDEmanX:

```
import bpy

def stop_playback(scene):
    if scene.frame_current == scene.frame_end:
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel(restore_frame=False)

# or restore frames:
def stop_playback_restore(scene):
    if scene.frame_current == scene.frame_end + 1:
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel(restore_frame=True)

# add one of these functions to frame_change_pre handler:
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(stop_playback)
```

Comment: why you set it to 70 it should be frame_end

Comment: @Chebhou thanks, I copied the code from the from blender artists forum